# How to make a scrollable view in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

Recently, I've built a simple game with AndEngine but I have no clue to how to make a level selector(scrollable view). I want a scrollable view to show three types of game difficulty such as "easy,normal,hard", but I cannot find any solutions nor any proper tutorial on AndEngine. Most of the tutorials I find on the web are mostly about settings up the project or some basic things. Are there some tips or samples? I would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check **Scrolling Level Selector** a simple vertical scrolling example.

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/scrolling-level-selector-t5112.html

You can check this thread, It fits for your requirement.

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/menu-scroll-example-t5740.html